# Why am I getting a ClassCastException as I try to get a property of type Long?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

On running the following snippet :

```
String hqlSelect = "select bookID from Issued where regID = " + regID;
    List list = sess.createQuery(hqlSelect).list();
    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Issued issued = (Issued) i.next(); // LINE : 46
        bookIdList.add(issued.getBookID());
    }
```

line number `46` generates an exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to pojo.Issued
```

In the query `bookID` and `regID` are of type `Long` and issued is a class that contains `bookID` and `regID`.

Why am I getting this exception ?

Comment: Well, it looks like your `sess.createQuery(hqlSelect).list()` returns a `List<Long>`... Why isn't the list generic by the way?

Answer (score 1):

try using below code.

```
String hqlSelect = "select new java.lang.Long(bookID) from Issued where regID = " + regID;
List<Long> list = (List<Long>)sess.createQuery(hqlSelect).list();
Iterator<Long> i = list.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) {
    bookIdList.add(i);
}
```

You can also use `for each` loop

```
for (Long i : list) {
bookIdList.add(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String hqlSelect = "select bookID from Issued where regID = " + regID;

This query seems like a normal native query. It will give Object[] List.

```
List<Object> list = sess.createNativeQuery(hqlSelect).list();
```

if u are using JPA query you can get Issued objects (if you have POJO Object for Issued)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to get bookID

```
String hqlSelect = "select bookID from Issued where regID = " + regID;
    List<Object[]> list = sess.createQuery(hqlSelect).list();

for (Object[] result : list) {        
    long bookId = ((Number) result[0]).longValue();
}
```

Comment: it returns a List<Long> not a list of object arrays!

Comment: No, hibernate always return  object in select statement. You need to cast it.

Comment: I was too tired to test this last night, but OP's query `select bookID from Issued where regID` should only return a List<Long>. A List<Object[]> is ONLY return on a select with multiple columns - which the OP IS NOT asking for. I tested if for createQuery and createSQLQuery, both returned List<Long> for above query.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the select clause for selecting objects in HQL (see [HQL Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-from)).
So you can just use the following HQL query:

```
String hqlSelect = "from Issued where regID = " + regID;
```

and the query it will return a list of objects which can be cast to Issued.